# Unable to configure yahoo.IN account in Thunderbird

Tags: email, thunderbird

I am unable to configure my yahoo.in account to Thunderbird. When I try to configure it it shows that

> Thunderbird fails to find settings for your email account.

Can anyone help?

But I am able to configure an @gmail.com account.

Comment: As it stands it is hard to tell what you are doing. Please either edit your post to make it a lot cleared and/or more generic.

Comment: @Hennes i tried to create as normal way.create new account -> from there i entered name,email,passwd.->continue. For gmail account it workd and account created.But for yahoo.in account this error occurd.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yahoo Mail doesn't offer POP/IMAP access for you to connect using an email client like Thunderbird - at least not unless you use [Yahoo Mail Plus](http://mailplus.mail.yahoo.com/).

If you are using Yahoo Mail Plus, [these settings should help](http://help.yahoo.com/l/in/yahoo/mail/yahoomail/mailplus/pop/pop-14.html):

> #### Incoming mail server settings
>
> - POP server: pop.mail.yahoo.com
> - Use SSL Port: 995
>
> #### Outgoing mail server (SMTP) settings
>
> - SMTP server: smtp.mail.yahoo.com
> - Use SSL
> - Port: 465
>
> #### Use authentication
>
> - Account Name/Login Name: Your Yahoo! Mail ID (your email address without the "@yahoo.com", for example, “jo.bloggs”)
> - Email Address: Your Yahoo! Mail address (for example, jo.bloggs@yahoo.com)
> - Password: Your Yahoo! Mail password

If you don't have Yahoo Mail Plus, then you can't use an email client.

Comment: i dnt have yahoo mail plus. so that means i cnt configure yahoo.in account? anyway thnkz

Answer (score 0):

I do not think that Yahoo Mail Plus is required.  I have been using Thunderbird with Yahoo for years and never paid anything.

My problem is that Thunderbird crashed due to my external hard drive becoming Read-Only and when I moved my profile to another hard drive I could no longer get Thunderbird to connect to Yahoo.com.ph.

Comment: This does not appear to answer the question.